# Create abstract tree problem from parser

Tags: java, tree, jflex

I need big help, I have two simple classes Tree and Node ( I put just interface to use less space on forum, I can easy modify those classes ), I also have flex file and parser file and need to create AST ( abstract syntax tree - to put tokens in Node objects and fill Tree in right way ).

```
public class Tree {
    Node root;
    public void AddNode(Node n){}
    public void Evaluate(){}
}

public class Node {
    public String value;
    public int type;
    Node left, right;
}
```

This is parser file

```
import java_cup.runtime.*;

parser code {:

    public boolean result = true; 

    public void report_fatal_error(String message, Object   info) throws java.lang.Exception {
        done_parsing();
        System.out.println("report_fatal_error");
        report_error();
    }

    public void syntax_error(Symbol cur_token) {
        System.out.println("syntax_error");
        report_error();
    }

    public void unrecovered_syntax_error(Symbol cur_token) throws java.lang.Exception {
        System.out.println("unrecovered_syntax_error");
        report_fatal_error("Fatalna greska, parsiranje se ne moze nastaviti", cur_token);
    }

    public void report_error(){
        System.out.println("report_error");
        result = false;
    }
:}

init with {: result = true; :};

/* Terminals (tokens returned by the scanner). */
terminal           AND, OR, NOT;
terminal           LPAREN, RPAREN;
terminal           ITEM;
terminal           OPEN, CLOSE, MON, MOFF, TIMEOUT, ESERR, BAE, I, O, BUS, EXT, PUSHB;
terminal           VAL, OK, BUS_BR_L, BUS_BR_R, SH_CRT_L, SH_CRT_R, BUS_ALL, EXT_ALL, NO_TIMEOUT, NO_ES_ERR, IBUS_OK, CFG_OK, SYNTAX;
terminal           OUT;

/* Non-terminals */
non terminal        extension;
non terminal Integer    expr;

/* Precedences */
precedence left AND, OR;

/* The grammar */

expr      ::= 
          |
            expr:e1 AND expr:e2 
          {: 
            //System.out.println("AND"); 
            RESULT = 1; 
            :} 
          | 
              expr:e1 OR expr:e2 
          {: 
            //System.out.println("OR"); 
            RESULT = 2; 
            :} 
          | 
              NOT expr:e1
          {: 
            //System.out.println("NOT"); 
            RESULT = 3; 
            :}
          | 
              LPAREN expr:e RPAREN     
          {: 
            //System.out.println("()"); 
            RESULT = 4; 
            :} 
          | 
              ITEM extension:e1
          {: 
            //System.out.println("ITEM."); 
            RESULT = 5; 
            :}
          | 
              error
          {: 
            System.out.println("error"); 
            parser.report_error();
            RESULT = 0; 
            :}
          ;

extension ::= 
              OPEN
          |   
              MON
          |   
              CLOSE
          |
              MOFF
          |
              TIMEOUT
          |
              ESERR
          |
              BAE
          |
              I
          |
              O
          |
              BUS
          |
              EXT
          |
              PUSHB
          |
              VAL
          |
              OK
          |
              BUS_BR_L
          |
              BUS_BR_R
          |
              SH_CRT_L
          |
              SH_CRT_R
          |
              BUS_ALL
          |
              EXT_ALL
          |
              NO_TIMEOUT
          |
              NO_ES_ERR
          |
              IBUS_OK
          |
              CFG_OK 
          |
              SYNTAX
          | 
              OUT
          ;
```

This is grammar

```
%%

%{
    public boolean result = true;

    //Puni expression sa tokenima radi reimenovanja
    public Expression expression=new Expression();
    //

    public ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> extensions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // ukljucivanje informacije o poziciji tokena
    private Symbol new_symbol(int type) {
            return new Symbol(type, yyline+1, yycolumn);
    }
    // ukljucivanje informacije o poziciji tokena
    private Symbol new_symbol(int type, Object value) {
            return new Symbol(type, yyline+1, yycolumn, value);
    }
%}

%cup

%xstate COMMENT

%eofval{ 
return new_symbol(sym.EOF);
%eofval}

%line
%column

%%
" " {}
"\b" {}
"\t" {}
"\r\n" {}
"\f" {}
"open" {extensions.add(sym.OPEN); return new_symbol(sym.OPEN);}
"close" {extensions.add(sym.CLOSE); return new_symbol(sym.CLOSE);}
"m_on" {extensions.add(sym.MON); return new_symbol(sym.MON);}
"m_off" {extensions.add(sym.MOFF); return new_symbol(sym.MOFF);}
"timeout" {extensions.add(sym.TIMEOUT); return new_symbol(sym.TIMEOUT);}
"es_err" {extensions.add(sym.ESERR); return new_symbol(sym.ESERR);}
"bae" {extensions.add(sym.BAE); return new_symbol(sym.BAE);}
"i" {extensions.add(sym.I); return new_symbol(sym.I);}
"o" {extensions.add(sym.O); return new_symbol(sym.O);}
"bus" {extensions.add(sym.BUS); return new_symbol(sym.BUS);}
"ext" {extensions.add(sym.EXT); return new_symbol(sym.EXT);}
"pushb" {extensions.add(sym.PUSHB); return new_symbol(sym.PUSHB);}
"val" {extensions.add(sym.VAL); return new_symbol(sym.VAL);}
"ok" {extensions.add(sym.OK); return new_symbol(sym.OK);}
"bus_br_l" {extensions.add(sym.BUS_BR_L); return new_symbol(sym.BUS_BR_L);}
"bus_br_r" {extensions.add(sym.BUS_BR_R); return new_symbol(sym.BUS_BR_R);}
"sh_crt_l" {extensions.add(sym.SH_CRT_L); return new_symbol(sym.SH_CRT_L);}
"sh_crt_r" {extensions.add(sym.SH_CRT_R); return new_symbol(sym.SH_CRT_R);}
"bus_all" {extensions.add(sym.BUS_ALL); return new_symbol(sym.BUS_ALL);}
"ext_all" {extensions.add(sym.EXT_ALL); return new_symbol(sym.EXT_ALL);}
"no_timeout" {extensions.add(sym.NO_TIMEOUT); return new_symbol(sym.NO_TIMEOUT);}
"no_es_err" {extensions.add(sym.NO_ES_ERR); return new_symbol(sym.NO_ES_ERR);}
"ibus_ok" {extensions.add(sym.IBUS_OK); return new_symbol(sym.IBUS_OK);}
"cfg_ok" {extensions.add(sym.CFG_OK); return new_symbol(sym.CFG_OK);}
"syntax" {extensions.add(sym.SYNTAX); return new_symbol(sym.SYNTAX);}
"out" {extensions.add(sym.OUT); return new_symbol(sym.OUT);}
"!" { return new_symbol(sym.NOT);}
"&" { return new_symbol(sym.AND);}
"|" { return new_symbol(sym.OR);}
"(" { return new_symbol(sym.LPAREN);}
")" { return new_symbol(sym.RPAREN);}
([[:jletter:]])[[:jletterdigit:]]* \. {items.add(yytext().substring(0, yytext().length()-1)); return new_symbol (sym.ITEM);}
. {result = false;}
```

Probem is how to create AST from here, I got on input expression  something like

> A.open && b.i
>   ? Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines in your Parser where you have commented out print statements like:

```
        //System.out.println("OR");
```

is where you'll want to maintain your AST using the Tree data structure you have.  Find out which token will create the tree, add something somewhere in the tree, etc based on your grammar.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I added my grammar, sorry, I didn't understand you very well. If I add there (where is System.println ), what if that is not leaf ( example expression AND expression ). Can you help me with simple example please ?

Comment: Lets take your example of 'Expression_1 AND Expression_2'.  You would have a subtree AND with left child Expression_1 and right child Expression_2.  You need to create that subtree in your AST and set the left child to Expression_1 and the right child to Expression_2.  Finally you would hook the subtree back up to the root.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I'm concern if expression_1 is (a.i && c.open) AND expression_2 is (d.i && e.i ) | d.open. I am gonna get list of trees ?

Comment: Think sub tree.  a.i && c.open is just another subtree.