# Change Object type in Java CUP

Tags: java, cup

I am creating a parser using CUP together with JFLex to create the scanner.

I was following this link [Parse tree generation with Java CUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033303/parse-tree-generation-with-java-cup) but I got stuck because I do not know how to change the type to **Node** because by default the type is Object.

I want the CUP case statements to look like the following

```
case 16: 
{
  Node RESULT =null; ... }
```

and not:

```
case 16: 
{
  Object RESULT =null; ...}
```

Comment: I cannot vote up yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type of the terminal / non terminal at their respective sections:

```
terminal [TYPE] TERM [, TERM]*;
non terminal [TYPE] NONTERM [, NONTERM]*;
```

The generated code of:

```
terminal Foo A,B,C;
non terminal BinaryExpression E0,E1;
non terminal BinaryOperator OP0,OP1;
/*etc*/
```

will be something like this:

```
 /*. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .*/
case 63: // E0 ::= E0 OP0 E1 
{
  BinaryExpression RESULT =null;
  BinaryExpression e0 = (BinaryExpression)((java_cup.runtime.Symbol) CUP$/* ... */.value;
  BinaryOperator op0 =  (BinaryOperator)((java_cup.runtime.Symbol) CUP$C/* ... */.value;
  BinaryExpression e1 = (BinaryExpression)((java_cup.runtime.Symbol) CUP$/* ... */.value;
  RESULT = new BinaryExpression(e0,op0,e2); 
  CUP$/*...*/$result = /*...*/
}
return CUP$ConstructorAST$result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to cast to Node? as below?

```
case 16: 
{
  Node RESULT = (Node) null; ... }
```

Comment: Yes.. what I am after is the command that I should write in CUP to generate that statement